# How can I wait for my api to send all the data in angular 11 when already use pipe and map

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, async-await, response

so, I'm looking for a solve  a problem that happens to me right now, in my application I´m calling  an API, how I am showing below:

```
getProgramContainer(shift: string,date : string,traffic: string ,status :string ): Observable<IprogramContainer[]> {
    return  this.http.get<IprogramContainer[]>(environment.apiUrl+shift+'/'+date+'/'+traffic+'/'+status)
                                              .pipe(
                                                   map(IprogramContainer=>{
                                                    //  console.log(IprogramContainer)
                                                      return IprogramContainer;
                                                    }),
                                                    catchError((err :HttpErrorResponse )=>{
                                                      console.log(err)
                                                      return throwError(null)
                                                    })
                                                   );
```

my point  with this snippet of code was receive all data through an `Observable`, in this  way I can get before my data  to be able to validate some data  and  using `map` to take my values before they arrive to my component.

```
getDataTable1(shift:string,date:string,traffic:string,status:string):any{
         return this.rprogramContainerService.getProgramContainer(shift, 
                                                          this.formatoFecha(date),
                                                          traffic,
                                                          status)
        .subscribe(
                  IprogramContainer =>{ this.IProgramContainerList = IprogramContainer;
                    console.log( this.IProgramContainerList);
                  },err =>{
                      console.log('No se recibieron datos');
                  }
        );
  }
```

in the code above, I get a called  that I did from my component, I thought trying to catch the data  in my service  I could waiting for the whole data response, however it was not, the fist thing the application shows in the `console.log` is my empty object  and continue with its course for late display my object with all data and I can't put these data in my report using jspdf cuz' the first to  print is the report and then I receive my data, so the report appears empty

```
GenerateReport():void{
    let rows: (string | number)[][] = [];
    let data =  this.getDataTable1(this.Form.get('PrmShift')?.value,this.Form.get('PrmDate')?.value,this.Form.get('PrmTraffic')?.value,this.Form.get('PrmStatus')?.value)

    console.log(data);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to do some modification in map method in your service then you want to use that data in your component, is that correct ?

Comment: in your variable "data" you has a reference to the **subscription**, not to the data. In general think that the services should return only observables, then you subscribe in the components and get the data into the subcribe function. If you want store the response of a httpClient.get -or another observable- you can use the rxjs operator "tap" instead "map"- that execute when someone subscribe to your service but not change the response

Comment: yes, I'm receiving the data in my service and then I want to take the response in my component, when my data  arrive to my component I'll convert the object to an array but my code in jspdf it's executing before I received the data.I've already tried with `tap` in my service but no works or at least I didn't know If that was the only thing I needed to change